# GridView RowCommand Triggering Unintended Function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, event-handling

I have a GridView that has a button inside a template field.When the button is clicked, I make a query to the database and dynamically create, input fields(a textbox and CuteEditor) and set their "text" property to the results of my query.

At that point an update button is created dynamically(I am setting the onClientClick property to the Function "Update Post"), so if the user changes any content inside those input fields they can update the database

The problem is that when the user clicks on the Button inside the GridView TemplateField, my funcion "UpdatePost" is being triggered when it should not be.

**What is causing UpdatePost to be triggered prematurely?**

Removing the OnClientClick solves the problem(The function does not trigger prematurely).

It is like OnClientClick is being triggered by the Click function of my button inside the GridView Template Field

```
Private Function UpdatePost()
    'Find subject and Post Content
    Dim myPh As PlaceHolder = plcEditor
    Dim EditorContent As CuteEditor.Editor = plcEditor.FindControl("editEditor")
    Dim editorSubject As TextBox = plcEditor.FindControl("editorSubject")
    Dim hiddenID As HiddenField = plcEditor.FindControl("hiddenID")
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratnewsConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim nCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim addCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim addCom As New SqlCommand("UPDATE News SET Subject = @Subject, [Content] = @Content WHERE (ID = @ID)", addCon)
    addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", editorSubject.Text)
    addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", hiddenID.Value)
    addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", Server.HtmlDecode(EditorContent.Text))
    Try
        addCon.Open()
        addCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        addCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception



    End Try

    Return True
End Function

Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "editPost" Then
        'Remove DataGrid'''''''''
        GridView1.Visible = False
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        Dim ID As String = GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''CREATE Controls for Placeholder
        Dim editEditor As New CuteEditor.Editor
        Dim hiddenID As New HiddenField
        hiddenID.ID = "hiddenID"
        hiddenID.Value = ID
        editEditor.ID = "editEditor"
        Dim subjectTXT As New TextBox
        subjectTXT.ID = "editorSubject"
        Dim br As New Literal
        Dim editButton As New Button
        Dim sbjLabel As New Label


        sbjLabel.Text = "Subject:   "

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        editEditor.AutoConfigure = CuteEditor.AutoConfigure.Simple
        br.Text = "<br/><br/>"
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(hiddenID)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(sbjLabel)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(subjectTXT)
        subjectTXT.Width = "100"
        subjectTXT.Height = "25"
        subjectTXT.CssClass = "editInput"
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(editEditor)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(editButton)
        editButton.Text = " Submit Changes "
        editButton.Height = 40
        editButton.Width = 300
        editButton.OnClientClick = UpdatePost()

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratnewsConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim nCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCom As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [News] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)", addCon)
        addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)


        Dim results As SqlDataReader
        addCon.Open()
        results = addCom.ExecuteReader
        While results.Read()
            Dim editText As String = results.Item("Content")
            Dim Subject As String = results.Item("Subject")
            editEditor.Text = editText
            subjectTXT.Text = Subject
        End While
        addCon.Close()




    End If
End Sub
```

**GRID-VIEW CODE**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    Width="776px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#D8D8D8" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="30" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="140" DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
            SortExpression="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date Published" 
            SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="grdEdit"  height="70" Width="200" runat="server" CommandName="editPost" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" Text="Edit Post" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2"  height="70" Width="200" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" Text="Delete Post" />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Red" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<asp:Button />` renders HTML that will trigger a postback.  The [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y200) property is for use with JavaScript and if you do not cancel the default action of submitting the form, then both your client-side event and the postback will still happen together.  Either use a standard button input (`<input type="button" />`) or try calling `e.preventDefault();` in your JavaScript function being used for the [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y200) property.

**Edit:**
I think the real answer here is that you are trying to use the [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y200) property expecting it to call server-side code.  It is meant for specifying a JavaScript function to call when the button is clicked.  The reason `UpdatePost` gets called is because that same button is automatically wired to trigger a postback.  And, because the CommandName matches your condition in the server-side event handler for that button, it is calling `UpdatePost` with this line of code:

```
editButton.OnClientClick = UpdatePost()
```

That line of code does not do what you think.  It's actually executing the `UpdatePost` method and setting the [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y200) property to the return value of `UpdatePost`.

Comment: Oh wow... Makes sense now. Thanks. How would I assign a click function to my dynamically created button?

Comment: @user1698144 You already have.  You have an event handler that is handling the `RowCommand` for the grid control.  Any `<asp:Button />` inside that grid will trigger a postback.  And, in your case, you have set a `CommandName` to one of those buttons and are actually checking its value in the event handler.  There may be more to your code, so I can't really give you a better answer.  It looks like you are trying to show an editor to edit the row, then save those changes using `UpdatePost`.

Comment: I was not referring to the item Template button. I was referring to the EditButton button(  Dim editButton As New Button)

Comment: @user1698144 `editButton` is still rendering an <asp:Button/> and will still cause a PostBack, but you're adding controls to the control tree in a way that is problematic anyway.  For events to be properly handled for controls, you must ensure the control is in the control tree before and after the event is fired.  There are actually quite a few more problems with your code.  I can really only answer the question at hand.